# Connection to DB with socket refused in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm aware of a ton of hits on SO and Google about this issue, still I have a unique problem it seems.

Error message:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Configuration

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        "host"      => "localhost:/var/run/mysqld4.sock",
        'port'      => '3304',
        "username"  => "admin",
        "password"  => "admin",
        "database"  => "frontend_generic",
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'pre_',
    ),
```

I confirmed that my database is running on port 3304, my prefix is correct, as are user, database and password.

For host I tried "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "http://127.0.0.1" and even the actual ip-address of the server.

Still, there is no luck or change. I tried using the exact same configuration in the local database.php file, but as expected, nothing changes.

Out of options, what am I missing here?

Update:

This is code from another app that works with this configuration. This is Kohana, not Laravel, but it works.

```
 "general" => array
        (
            "type"       => "mysql",
            "connection" => array
            (
                "hostname"   => "localhost:/var/run/mysqld4.sock",
                "username"   => "admin",
                "password"   => "admin",
                "persistent" => FALSE,
                "database"   => "frontend_generic",
            ),
            "table_prefix" => "pre_",
            "charset"      => "utf8",
            "caching"      => FALSE,
            "profiling"    => TRUE,
        ),
```

Comment: Are you certain the database is actually running? How did you confirm it's running? This error indicates it couldn't find any database at all.

Comment: I have another application that uses the database and it works fine. It doesn't lock the database.

Comment: can you please add `dd('test');` directly after your connections array in the database file and say if it is hit

Comment: With a comma instead of a semicolon I do get a string "Test". Otherwise I get (ofc) a syntax errorrrr.

Comment: @Chilion Are the server details for the other app exactly the same as the config here?

Comment: What does the `:` behind `localhost` do (while specifying db host)? You specified the port seperately... Have you tried whiping that away?

Comment: one : is for sockets, 2 :: is for port :). But yes indeed I tried it without. No luck tough.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

You should change "host" to the actual server IP adres, and nothing else. So, get rid of the socket stuff.

Comment: This does not answer the issue regarding "connection to DB using socket". The answer below does.

Comment: Since a socket connection is faster this answer is incomplete and misleading. The answer below from @ThievingSix should be marked as correct

Answer (score 19):

When using sockets with laravel 5, use the `unix_socket` config instead of `host` and `port`.

While changing to IP addresses does work, there can be advantages to using sockets when the database server is on the same machine.

Correcting the configuration originally posted:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'           => 'mysql',
        "unix_socket"      => "/var/run/mysqld4.sock",
        "username"         => "admin",
        "password"         => "admin",
        "database"         => "frontend_generic",
        'charset'          => 'utf8',
        'collation'        => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'           => 'pre_',
    ),
```

Comment: This worked for me connecting from Eloquent to Google Cloud SQL. The "dsn" value doesn't do much but using the "unix_socket" key worked. Thank you.

Comment: This answer should be absolutely positioned to the top.

Answer (score -1):

This is what the array should look like in Laravel 5:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

In your .env file, located in the project root, please change the settings you need to adjust and try it again like this. It's really hard to say what could cause this issue, so just give this a try.

Example .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

After creating the file with your credentials, as I commented, please call the file .env and put it in the root of your project. Also make sure to check todays Laravel log, located at storage/logs/laravel-todays_date.txt and report any errors here.

Comment: These is no .env file in my project, also not a hidden file.

Comment: If you haven't deleted it, there is one, if still not, just create one, I'll post how it looks like

Comment: I don't see why I should create a .env file. The .env file is not needed for Laravel to communicate with a database. It should work from the database.php file

Comment: Anyway, try to set the array the way laravel excpects it to be

Comment: Its not different from what I have, only strict, I added that, still no luck :()